# What is the role of index in the callback function of click in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

The following code works. I want to understand why is `i` used there as index in the argument list of the callback function. What is its purpose? If I remove `i` from the argument list of the call back function, it doesn't work. Why?

```
$("#btn1").click(function(){
  $("#test1").text(function(i, origText){
    return "Old text: " + origText + " New text: Hello world!
    (index: " + i + ")";
  });
});
```

Comment: If you remove `i`, then `origText` becomes the first parameter. And the first parameter is always the index.

Comment: Image you define a function as `function add(a,b) { return a+b; }` then you *call* that function with `add(1,2)` - callbacks are the same, but the other way around.  Rather than call a function in a library, the library is calling your function.  The library is doing `add(1,2)`.  If you remove the `i` from your call back definition then it's the same as changing your function `function add(a) { }` - you're not removing `i`, you shifting `origText` to the first position - it's still `i`, doesn't matter what it's called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To many of the jQuery methods, you can pass:

1. `undefined` (nothing)
2. a value (a string, a number, a boolean, an object...)
3. a function statement (a callback).

So focussing on the 3rd one. When you provide a function statement, consider that the method does a couple things before calling the passed-in function. That is why it is called a `callback`. So `.text(callback)` is calling (read executing) your `callback` by passing in some arguments.

In this case, the first agument is a number representing the index of the matched element. So you can inagine a loop here. The second is the original text of the matched element.

[Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function)

So you have to write the callback taking this in account. You are not forced to use the arguments, but it's there for you to use.

so...

```
$(selector).text(function(i, origText){
  
  // outputs a number
  console.log(i)
  
  // outputs a tring
  console.log(origText)
  
  // Expected to be returned is a string to use to set the element's text
  return "Something else"
}
```

In the above, since the argument where not used in order to build the returned string, it is the same as:

```
$(selector).text("Something else")
```

But using a function allows you to use the arguments of the callback in the text to be set:

```
$(selector).text(function(i, origText){
  
  // outputs a string containing the index number in the $(selector) collection
  return "I am element " + i;
}
```

Or to apply some logic like:

```
$(selector).text(function(i, origText){
  
  // Only the text of the second matching element will be changed (index is zero-based)
  if(i == 1){
    return "I am element " + i;
  }else{
    return origText
  }
}
```

Now, it is up to you to name the arguments... If that was the question.

```
$(selector).text(function(pineapple, banana){
  
  // outputs a number
  console.log(pineapple)
  
  // outputs a tring
  console.log(banana)
  
  // Expected to be returned is a string to use to set the element's text
  return "Something else"
}
```

If you are only interested in the `banana` argument, you still have to name the first in order to name and use the second. Just do not use `pineapple` in the function body if it is useless to you.

Hoping it is helpful. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The callback function has two parameters: the index of the current element in the list of elements selected and the original value. If you remove the `i`, then callback function is consider first parameter is `origText`